# How to handle file upload validations using Flask-Marshmallow?

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-marshmallow

I'm working with `Flask-Marshmallow` for validating `request` and `response` schemas in `Flask app`. I was able to do simple validations for `request.form` and `request.args` when there are simple fields like `Int`, `Str`, `Float` etc.

I have a case where I need to upload a file using a form field - `file_field`. It should contain the file content.

How can I validate if this field is present or not and what is the format of file etc.

Is there any such field in `Marshmallow` that I can use like `fields.Int()` or `fields.Str()`

I have gone through the documentation [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields) but haven't found any such field.

Comment: The related issue at GitHub: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-marshmallow/issues/5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `fields.Raw`:

```py
import marshmallow

class CustomSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
  file = marshmallow.fields.Raw(type='file')
```

If you are using Swagger, you would then see something like this:

[image]

Then in your `view` you can access the file content with `flask.request.files`.

For a full example and more advanced topics, check out my [project](https://github.com/rena2damas/ticket-manager).

Comment: What about multiple files field?

Answer (score 2):

As of 7 December, 2022, marshmallow v3.19.0 doesn't work with `Raw(metadata={})` or `Raw(type='binary/file')`. Hence I tried `Field()` and it works fine.
To validate JPG, PNG files, I do that while `@validates_schema` by catching it's file type. I have also saved the file after in `@post_load` method.

```py
class MySchema(Schema):
    icon_url = Field(metadata={'type': 'string', 'format': 'byte'}, allow_none=True)
    
    @validates_schema
    def validate_uploaded_file(self, in_data, **kwargs):
        errors = {}
        file: FileStorage = in_data.get("icon_url", None)

        if file is None:
            # if any file is not uploaded, skip validation
            pass

        elif type(file) != FileStorage:
            errors["icon_url"] = [
                f"Invalid content. Only PNG, JPG/JPEG files accepted"]
            raise ValidationError(errors)

        elif file.content_type not in {"image/jpeg", "image/png"}:
            errors["icon_url"] = [
                f"Invalid file_type: {file.content_type}. Only PNG, JPG/JPEG images accepted."]
            raise ValidationError(errors)

        return in_data
    

    @post_load
    def post_load(self, loaded_obj, **kwargs):
        if loaded_obj.icon_url:
            sec_filename = secure_filename(
                f'{loaded_obj.name}.{loaded_obj.icon_url.filename.split(".")[-1]}')
            loaded_obj.icon_url.save(
                f"{current_app.config['PUBLIC_IMAGES_FOLDER']}{sec_filename}")
            loaded_obj.icon_url = f'{current_app.config["PUBLIC_IMAGES_URL"]}{sec_filename}'
        return loaded_obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `Field` or `Raw` field to represent a general field, then set the correct OpenAPI properties for this field (i.e. `type` and `format`).

In OpenAPI 3, you should set `type` to `string` instead of `file`, then set `format` to `binary` or `byte` based on your file content:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class MySchema(Schema):
  file = fields.Raw(metadata={'type': 'string', 'format': 'binary'})
```

See the [docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#file) for more details.

By the way, from marshmallow 3.10.0, using keyword arguments to pass OpenAPI properties (`description`, `type`, `example` etc.) was deprecated and will be removed in marshmallow 4, use the `metadata` dict to pass them instead.